# Error al levantar Servidor en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby

Despues de iniciar mi proyecto desde la ruta especifica y ejecutar el comando `rails s`, me origina el sgte error:

```
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>= 0) x86-mins machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Modifiqué el `Gemfile`, pero sigue teniendo el mismo error.

Trabajo con Windows.
Ya esta verificado las versiones de Ruby, Rails, Git y GEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece ser un problema con `tzinfo-data`, podrías verificar si está instalado con el siguiente comando:

```
gem list
```

De no estar instalado, debes ejecutar

```
gem install tzinfo-data
```

Y una vez instalado, debería estar solucionado el problema.

Comment: El error parece subsanado ese problema, ahora bien me genero otros repositorios que no estaban y me encuentro en coffee-rails el cual no a podido instalarse correctamente, pero me sigue arrojando error a pesar que ya esta instalado: coffee-rails (4.2.1, 4.1.0) esto aparece al ejecutar gem list

Comment: Dentro de las opciones a modificar me aparece: Instalar Bundle, al ejecutar em sale lo sgte: bundle install
ubygems.org/

 for
.8/rack-test-0.6.3.gemspec.rz.
ng a man-in-the-middle attack,
CA certificates needed for ver

es, see bit.ly/ruby-ssl. To co
 and change 'https' to 'http'.

Comment: @KevinMartinez prueba a editar el archivo `Gemfile` cambiando el enlace de `https` a `http`.

Comment: Efectivamente, como indica @Madh, edita el `Gemfile` (el cual es el archivo encargado de registrar las dependencias del proyecto). Luego no te olvides de ejecutar `bundle install` para que instale las gemas nuevas. En cuanto a las gemas nuevas que te aparecen, es normal que aparezcan, debido a que son gemas de las que depende. Para verificar las gemas de las que depende puedes ejecutar `gem dependency tzinfo-data`

Answer (score 0):

Una de las primeras cosas que es necesario hacer una vez definido un nuevo proyecto en Ruby, ya sea creando una gema o desarrollando una aplicación en Ruby on Rails, es instalar las dependencias necesarias. Lo habitual es que exista un archivo de texto llamado `Gemfile` en el directorio raíz del proyecto, que describe todas las dependencias necesarias.

[`Bundler`](https://bundler.io/) es una gema encargada de instalar o actualizar las gemas requeridas por un proyecto. Básicamente lee el contenido del `Gemfile` e instala todas aquellas gemas que no estén instaladas en el sistema sin necesidad de instalar cada gema una a una. Para instalarlo solo necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

```
gem install bundler
```

Una vez instalado, bastaría con ejecutar desde la raíz del proyecto:

```
bundle install
```